# Rubygame on rails : Support of audio formats(mp3, ogg) while using Rubygame gem on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, rubygame

I have tried support of midi, mp3, ogg, aiff and wav files on ruby interpreter after installing rubygame and it works fine. I Used the Rubygame::Music class and methods in it for the same.

But when i use and try it on the rails framework only midi format is working and the rest of the formats(mp3, ogg, aiff and wav) are getting executed but  there is no sound.

After some googling i saw this : http://blog.rubygame.org/2008/04/01/rubygame-on-rails/
As per it,
    "Currently, the only audio support in RGoR (Rubygame over rails) is playing MIDI versions of 1990′s pop songs.However, I hope to fix these and other issues in future releases."

Is this fixed now on latest versions and has anyone tried these formats(mp3, ogg) on RGoR?